# Mac Terminal Foreach Command Not Found While Running Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to run a script in the terminal but I am getting the error message that the foreach command is not found. I've been trying to find an answer online for the past 6 hours but I can't seem to find anything. Can you please let me know why this is out-putting ' line 20: foreach: command not found'?

Script Here:

```
#!/bin/csh
# Source name: fa_extract
# Author name: ----
# Last modified by: Apr 29, 2013
# Date modified: Apr 29, 2013
# Program description: extract FA, AD, RA values
# Main function: extract FA, AD, RD, MD, into txt files
# Variable description: age; wt, waytotal


echo "# Source name: fa_extract"
echo "# Author name: ----"
echo "# Last modified by: Apr 29, 2013"
echo "# Date modified: Apr 29, 2013"
echo "# Program description: extract FA, AD, RA values"
echo "# Main function: extract FA, AD, RD, MD, into txt files"
echo "# Variable description: age; wt, waytotal"

#1st level
foreach sub$(01_007_c/01_007_c_L 01_007_c/01_007_c_R 01_012_c/01_012_c_L 01_012_c/01_012_c_R 01_013_c/01_013_c_L 01_013_c/01_013_c_R 01_014_c/01_014_c_L 01_014_c/01_014_c_R 01_015_c/01_015_c_L 01_015_c/01_015_c_R 01_029_p/01_029_p_L 01_029_p/01_029_p_R 01_035_p/01_035_p_L 01_035_p/01_035_p_R 01_036_p/01_036_p_L 01_036_p/01_036_p_R 01_037_p/01_037_p_L 01_037_p/01_037_p_R 01_038_p/01_038_p_L 01_038_p/01_038_p_R 01_040_p/01_040_p_L 01_040_p/01_040_p_R 01_041_p/01_041_p_L 01_041_p/01_041_p_R 01_042_p/01_042_p_L 01_042_p/01_042_p_R 01_043_p/01_034_p_L 01_043_p/01_043_p_R 01_044_p/01_044_p_L 01_044_p/01_044_p_R 01_045_p/01_045_p_L 01_045_p/01_045_p_R 01_046_p/01_046_p_L 01_046_p/01_046_p_R)

cd ~/Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/${sub}/

echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
pwd


set wt=`cut -f2 -d '' waytotal`#normalization by waytotal
echo "waytotal = $wt"
fslmaths fdt_paths.nii.gz -div $wt fdt_paths_fa_norm.nii.gz 
fslmaths fdt_paths_fa_norm.nii.gz -thrP 40 -bin fdt_paths_fa_bin.nii.gz # threshold by thrP40 & binarize

fslmaths *_DTI_FA.nii.gz -mas fdt_paths_fa_bin.nii.gz fa_masked.nii.gz # masking FA maps...................FA
fslstats fa_masked.nii.gz -M > fa.txt

fslmaths *_DTI_L2.nii.gz -mas fdt_paths_fa_bin.nii.gz L2_masked.nii.gz # masking L maps..................RD
fslmaths *_DTI_L3.nii.gz -mas fdt_paths_fa_bin.nii.gz L3_masked.nii.gz
fslmaths L2_masked.nii.gz -add L3_masked.nii.gz L2_L3_masked.nii.gz
fslmaths L2_L3_masked.nii.gz -div 2 rd.nii.gz
fslstats rd.nii.gz -M > rd.txt

fslmaths *_DTI_L1.nii.gz -mas fdt_paths_fa_bin.nii.gz ad.nii.gz # masking L maps..................AD
fslstats ad.nii.gz -M > ad.txt

fslmaths *_DTI_MD.nii.gz -mas fdt_paths_fa_bin.nii.gz md.nii.gz # masking L maps..................MD
fslstats md.nii.gz -M > md.txt

end # <<<<<<<<<subject loop ends
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>1st level done" 

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~2nd level

rm -rf /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/fa/athletes*.txt
rm -rf /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/fa/controls*.txt


# athletes
foreach sub$(01_007_c/01_007_c_L 01_007_c/01_007_c_R 01_012_c/01_012_c_L 01_012_c/01_012_c_R 01_013_c/01_013_c_L 01_013_c/01_013_c_R 01_014_c/01_014_c_L 01_014_c/01_014_c_R 01_015_c/01_015_c_L 01_015_c/01_015_c_R 01_029_p/01_029_p_L 01_029_p/01_029_p_R 01_035_p/01_035_p_L 01_035_p/01_035_p_R 01_036_p/01_036_p_L 01_036_p/01_036_p_R 01_037_p/01_037_p_L 01_037_p/01_037_p_R 01_038_p/01_038_p_L 01_038_p/01_038_p_R 01_040_p/01_040_p_L 01_040_p/01_040_p_R 01_041_p/01_041_p_L 01_041_p/01_041_p_R 01_042_p/01_042_p_L 01_042_p/01_042_p_R 01_043_p/01_034_p_L 01_043_p/01_043_p_R 01_044_p/01_044_p_L 01_044_p/01_044_p_R 01_045_p/01_045_p_L 01_045_p/01_045_p_R 01_046_p/01_046_p_L 01_046_p/01_046_p_R)

cd /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/${sub}/
cat             fa.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_fa.txt
cat             rd.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_rd.txt
cat             ad.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_ad.txt
cat             md.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_md.txt
#cat            ../age.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athltes_age.txt
cat           ../seg_0.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_seg_0.txt
cat               ../seg_1.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_seg_1.txt
cat               ../seg_2.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/athletes_seg_2.txt

end
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>2nd level athletes done" 

# controls
foreach sub$(01_007_c/01_007_c_L 01_007_c/01_007_c_R 01_012_c/01_012_c_L 01_012_c/01_012_c_R 01_013_c/01_013_c_L 01_013_c/01_013_c_R 01_014_c/01_014_c_L 01_014_c/01_014_c_R 01_015_c/01_015_c_L 01_015_c/01_015_c_R 01_029_p/01_029_p_L 01_029_p/01_029_p_R 01_035_p/01_035_p_L 01_035_p/01_035_p_R 01_036_p/01_036_p_L 01_036_p/01_036_p_R 01_037_p/01_037_p_L 01_037_p/01_037_p_R 01_038_p/01_038_p_L 01_038_p/01_038_p_R 01_040_p/01_040_p_L 01_040_p/01_040_p_R 01_041_p/01_041_p_L 01_041_p/01_041_p_R 01_042_p/01_042_p_L 01_042_p/01_042_p_R 01_043_p/01_034_p_L 01_043_p/01_043_p_R 01_044_p/01_044_p_L 01_044_p/01_044_p_R 01_045_p/01_045_p_L 01_045_p/01_045_p_R 01_046_p/01_046_p_L 01_046_p/01_046_p_R)# >>>>>>>>>subject loop

cd /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/${sub}/
cat             fa.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_fa.txt
cat             rd.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_rd.txt
cat             ad.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_ad.txt
cat             md.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_md.txt
#cat            ../age.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_age.txt
cat           ../seg_0.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_seg_0.txt
cat           ../seg_1.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_seg_1.txt
cat           ../seg_2.txt >> /Desktop/OBI_pre_process/DTI/Tractography/SLF/2nd_level/thrP40/N21_17/controls_seg_2.txt

end
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>2nd level controls done" 
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>ALL DONE !"
```

Comment: Are you executing your script by saying `bash filename`?  If so, it needs to be `csh filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason its failing because csh has foreach loop no other shell does.
so if you try to execute the script by anyother shell it will fail.

since you already have `#!/bin/csh` you can execute the script using `./scriptname` but if you are intended to execute it within someother shell`------`

replace for each line with following

```
for sub in $(echo "all the strings seperated by a space")
 do 

 \# rest of your script inside for should come here

done         #done is replacing end in your case
```

if you cannot use `echo "string SEPERATED by spaces"` then you can use `cut` with the delimeter you have.

I am not able to figure our delimeter you are using in foreach statement.